# Issues with newest version (cassandra 1.15)

Tags: cassandra

I tried installing newest cassandra version using the tarball binary available at -

http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=/cassandra/1.1.5/apache-cassandra-1.1.5-bin.tar.gz

I followed the instructions provided from the  the getting started page.

But when i run cassandra by ./cassandra -f , i get the following error#

```
amt@amtlt2:~/Downloads/apache-cassandra-1.1.5/bin$ ./cassandra -f
xss =  -ea -javaagent:./../lib/jamm-0.2.5.jar -XX:
+UseThreadPriorities-XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=42 -Xms4G
Xmx4G -Xmn800M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xss180k
```

P.S. i am installing on a server.

> well i don,t have a problem with java because i am running the latest version and this version works in my other PC where cassandra is configured.

```
amt@amtlt2:~/Downloads/apache-cassandra-1.1.5/bin$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_24"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.4) (6b24-1.11.4-1ubuntu0.12.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

> and i also feel its got nothing to do with heap size because its set to very high value

```
# The example HEAP_NEWSIZE assumes a modern 8-core+ machine for decent pause
# times. If in doubt, and if you do not particularly want to tweak, go with
# 100 MB per physical CPU core.

MAX_HEAP_SIZE="4G"
HEAP_NEWSIZE="800M"
```

> > the interesting thing is, if i follow same instructions and download the (unsupported) cassandra 1.12 release version. It works like a gem with same configuration as i did above.

Any help really appreciated.Point out in case i am doing something wrong here.

Comment: It looks like your description is missing the actual error message.

Comment: @jbellis : Well actually cassandra doesn't fire up . This is the message i get ( Not sure if this considered an error or not).                                                               xss =  -ea -javaagent:./../lib/jamm-0.2.5.jar -XX:
+UseThreadPriorities-XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=42 -Xms4G
Xmx4G -Xmn800M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xss180k

Comment: I am late, but what do the logs show?

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually have an error being logged.  `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` is actually a command-line option to the `java` command telling it to do a heap dump if it OOMs.

Comment: @ rs_atl : Thank you, well i understood what you are trying to tell. But unfortunately i could not make cassandra run.

Comment: Updating java solves the exception issue. Glad it worked :)         java version "1.7.0_07"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea7 2.3.2) (7u7-2.3.2-1ubuntu0.12.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.2-b09, mixed mode)